# Play Framework 2.2 - functional test fails with type mismatch

Tags: playframework-2.2

I've just upgraded to Play 2.2, and since the `Helpers` have changed, my test isn't compiling anymore.

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {
  import controllers._

  "Application" should {

    "test WS logic" in new WithServer {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get()).status must equalTo(OK)
    }

  }
}
```

gives the following compile error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response]
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[?]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's just a name clash between `play.api.test.Helpers.await` and `org.specs2.matcher.FutureMatchers.await`.

You could just refer to the play helper more explicitly (or rename your import):

```
Helpers.await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get()).status must equalTo(OK)
```

The following is probably better, however, which hasn't made it into the documentation yet:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/PlaySpecification.scala

So simply extend `PlaySpecification` instead of `Specification` in your test:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

class ApplicationSpec extends PlaySpecification {
  import controllers._

  "Application" should {

    "test WS logic" in new WithServer {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get()).status must equalTo(OK)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I think the first code example should be Helpers.await(...)